# undefined index issue even when data is in the array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am accessing an array object being transferred from model to view. When I print that array it shows complete info what I want, but when I implement foreach on that array and try to access an index it gives me an error of undefined index.

**the model code is**

```
public function fetch()
        {

$queryy=$this->db->select('*')
            ->from('selleritem')
            ->get();
            $data=$queryy->result();

            foreach($data as $datas)
            {
                $pid=$datas->pid ;
$query= $this->db->limit('1')
->select('*')
     ->where('pid', $pid)             
  ->get('selleritemimages'); 

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
         foreach ($query->result() as $row)
         {
            $data[] = $row;
         }
        return $data;
        //print_r($data);
    }
}
```

**the controller code is:**

```
public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('fetchindex');

        $fetch= array($this->fetchindex->fetch());  

        $this->load->view('welcome_message',['fetch'=>$fetch]);

    }
}
```

**the view code is**
**printing the array in view shows .**

```
print_r($fetch);

    foreach ( $fetch as $ff) {

    echo $ff["pid"].'hh<br>';

    }
```

**printing the array in view shows .**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 2 
            [name] => fashionable kurta for men 
            [gender] => groom 
            [price] => 11213 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => Rent 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 4 
            [product] => kurta 
            [available] => 9 
            [uid] => 2 
            [ucid] => 7 
            [rating] => 0 
            [rating_users] => 0 
        ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 1 
            [name] => suit fro groom 
            [gender] => groom 
            [price] => 12345 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => Sale 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 3 
            [product] => suits 
            [available] => 6 
            [uid] => 2 
            [ucid] => 11 
            [rating] => 22 
            [rating_users] => 5 
        ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 3 
            [name] => sherwani 
            [gender] => groom 
            [price] => 12133 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => Rent 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 5 
            [product] => sherwani 
            [available] => 10 
            [uid] => 4 
            [ucid] => 10 
            [rating] => 22 
            [rating_users] => 5 
        ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 4 
            [name] => branded shoes for groom 
            [gender] => groom 
            [price] => 3232 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => sale 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 6 
            [product] => foot wear 
            [available] => 9 
            [uid] => 4 
            [ucid] => 12 
            [rating] => 22 
            [rating_users] => 5 
        ) 
        [4] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 5 
            [name] => watches for groom 
            [gender] => groom 
            [price] => 33232 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => Sale 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 7 
            [product] => watches 
            [available] => 10 
            [uid] => 2 
            [ucid] => 18 
            [rating] => 24 
            [rating_users] => 6 
        ) 
        [5] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 6 
            [name] => watches for groom 
            [gender] => groom 
            [price] => 12133 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => Sale 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 8 
            [product] => watches 
            [available] => 10 
            [uid] => 1 
            [ucid] => 18 
            [rating] => 22 
            [rating_users] => 5 
        ) 
        [6] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 9 
            [name] => Branded bags 
            [gender] => bride 
            [price] => 22353 
            [description] => branded bags for sale 
            [rent_sale] => Sale 
            [features] => branded bags for sale 
            [pid] => 9 
            [product] => bags 
            [available] => 7 
            [uid] => 1 
            [ucid] => 3 
            [rating] => 53 
            [rating_users] => 20 
        ) 
        [7] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 10 
            [name] => Branded bags 
            [gender] => bride 
            [price] => 22353 
            [description] => Item Description 
            [rent_sale] => Sale 
            [features] => Key Features 
            [pid] => 10 
            [product] => bags 
            [available] => 8 
            [uid] => 1 
            [ucid] => 3 
            [rating] => 39 
            [rating_users] => 16 
        ) 
        [8] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 11 
            [image] => 1582863614kurta.jpg 
            [pid] => 4 
            [uid] => 2 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Below is the error what I'm getting:

> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: pid Filename:
>   views/welcome_message.php Line Number: 33

Comment: `Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: pid Filename: views/welcome_message.php Line Number: 33`? where is that line? can we see your view page code?

Comment: try like this : echo $ff->pid.'hh<br>';

Comment: I have posted a answer for you should help

Answer (score 2):

Because it is Codeigniter Object, not an Array.
And also see that your result object array is inside 0 index.
So, try fetching and getting data this way.

```
<?php foreach ( $fetch[0] as $ff) { 
     echo $ff->pid;
} ?>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$objects = json_decode($fetch);
$finalResult = (Array)$objects[0];
foreach($finalResult as $result){
    echo $result->pid.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your `foreach` like this:

```
foreach ($fetch[0] as $ff)
{
     echo $ff["pid"].'hh<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$query->result_array()` instead of `$query->result()`  If you read through the entire user guide, it should answer a few of your questions.

- http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html
- http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model
- http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Better way

```
$this->load->model('fetchindex');

$data['fetch'] = $this->fetchindex->fetch();  

// You can load views like so instead of using includes on view.
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('welcome_message',  $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Model

Filename: Fetchindex.php

```
<?php 

class Fetchindex extends CI_Model {

public function fetch()
{
    $data = array();

    $query = $this->db->get('selleritem');

    foreach ($query->result() as $result)
    {
        $this->db->where('pid', $result->pid);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $sub_query = $this-db->get('selleritemimages');

        if ($sub_query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {

            foreach ($sub_query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = array(
                   'somecolumn' => $row['somecolumn']
                   // Add other items you need
                );

            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($fetch as $item) {?>
     <?php echo $item["somecolumn"];?><br/>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($fetch[0] as $ff)
{
 echo $ff["pid"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.